# Who are these in my Windows Media Player?

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, windows-media-player

[image]

My laptop detects these people when I turn on my `Windows Media Player`. I guess these are the people connected to the same ISP as I am.

How do I block them ??

*Note: I can actually open their libraries and play what they have. Which, the other way around, is a breach of my privacy*

Comment: Are you using public wifi of some sort?  I used to see this when I used iTunes and airport wifi, where people would be sharing their libraries.  I'd imagine that Media Player has some way to disable sharing, just like iTunes does.

Comment: @ernie No , I am not. I have a cable connection via RJ45 :) I found the solution though :)

Comment: Just turn off `Network Discovery`

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can solve this issue by disabling the `Windows Media Player Network Sharing Service` from `Services.msc`.

That service is what shares your music and (what I believe) probes the network for other devices to share music with.

Answer (score 2):

Click on **File** -> **Work Offline**. That way your Media Player goes off the grid